# Rotated shadow text

Tags: html, css

I was wanting to have text shadow on this horizontal flat surface and the words are floating above the surface. The shadow will be angled to fit on the surface. Any way to do this? I am using css and html only.

[image: Desired outcome]

```css
.b {
  float:left;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-top:10%;
  padding: 50px 100px;
  background:#DF0000;
  box-shadow: inset 20px 0 50px 0 #900000, inset -20px 0 50px 0 #900000, 0 10px 20px #000000;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 20%;
  border-top-right-radius: 20%;
}
.b2 {
  float:left;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-top:112px;
  padding: 30px 100px;
  background:#760000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all ease-in-out 200ms;
}
.b2:hover {
  float:left;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:20%;
  margin-top:120px;
  padding: 30px 100px;
  background:#760000;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0 #000000;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b2">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Sorry, the snippet changes the code. Look at the picture. I want there to be text on top of the button. THe text shadow will lie down on the button surface.

Comment: Can you show us (1) your code and (2) the expected outcome?

Comment: It's unclear to me how the CSS you posted relates to the outcome you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You will need two copies of the text. One will be the text itself, and have no shadow. The other will be the shadow caster.

You can make the text `color: transparent` to only have its shadow visible.

```css
#shadow {
  font-size: 24pt;
  margin: 20px;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div id="shadow">SHADOWS</div>
```

Comment: The Snippet doesn't show anything. Possibly because `text-shadow: 0 0 6px 1px black;` is an invalid property, did you add too many 0's by mistake?

Comment: What are you using to test this?  I'm just getting a blank render in chrome.  Echoing the comment above this one; did you perhaps mean `box-shadow`?

Comment: The color is transparent.

Comment: Guess Chrome still doesn't support `text-shadow` properly... Try IE, where [it works perfectly](http://i.imgur.com/xJRh2XA.png) ;)

Comment: Firefox doesn't show anything too. `text-shadow` doesn't have the correct syntax. It must be 2 or 3 values and optional a color value. 4 values are too much. See [w3scools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp) or [latest W3C document](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-decor-3/#text-shadow-property)

Comment: Huh. So what happened to the `spread` property? How else would I get a "border" shadow than `0 0 0 1px black`?

Comment: There is no spread property in text shadows, This is misleading in the text shadow definition , that it is almost as a box-shadow... but lacks the spread property

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt, using a pseudo element to create the shadow, and a skew on it to creat the angled perspective.

```css
.base { 
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: 40px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px 6px gray;
}

#text {
   color: wheat;
   font-size: 90px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 162px;
   top: 118px;
   z-index: 10;
}

#text:after {
    content: attr(data-text);
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    left: 23px;
    top: 10px;
    transform: skewX(-40deg);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black, 0px 0px 15px black;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="base"></div>
<div id="text" data-text="TEXT">TEXT</div>
```

Comment: That is just what I need. Thanks.